# sbt test ends with No tests to run for test:test under Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sbt

As a former Java developer who is used to using Jenkins to launch JUnit tests every time a build is performed, I would love to get my Specs to run in a similar manner.

When running `sbt test` in the command line, the test cases that I have set up run just fine. Below is the output from the test run:

```
    [info] MySqlStoreSpec
    [info] 
    [info] MySqlStore Spec should
    [info] + getUserIdFromEmail
    [info] + getUserUserProperties
    [info] + getUserHashFromEmail
    [info] + md5
    [info] + getUserContextFromStripeId
    [info] 
    [info] 
    [info] Total for specification MySqlStoreSpec
    [info] Finished in 24 ms
    [info] 5 examples, 0 failure, 0 error
```

When I run the build in Jenkins, I get the following message:

```
    [info] No tests to run for test:test
```

I suspect that the issue with not kicking off the tests has to do with my `sbt` setup in Jenkins. In the configuration for the build, I am using sbt launcher `0.12.4` and actions `test`. Does anyone have any experience with getting specs2 to run on Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the build being performed on the wrong directory. Once the project was checked out from git, it needed to move into a subdirectory to get to the project files. It seems that SBT reports a successful run even if it finds no project files.

Comment: I tried. I must wait two days between posting the question and accepting my own answer.

Comment: thanks, 2013 question and answer found helpful in 2023!!